# MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I am using below command to execute sql commands in seperate SQL file.

```
mysql -uuser -ppasswrod host_name SCHMA_NAME -e "set @PACK_NAME=${ownerId};source DELTA_TRUNCATE.sql ;"
```

DELTA_TRUNCATE.sql file contens is:

```
SET @PROC_CALL=CONCAT('CALL ',@PACK_NAME||'.TRUNCATE_NORMAL_TABLE(\'IDSADLXQDWDWT\')');
PREPARE PRC_CALL_STMT FROM @PROC_CALL;EXECUTE PRC_CALL_STMT;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE PRC_CALL_STMT;
```

while executing above command as part of a unix script i am getting below error.

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for
>   the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

If i execute as normal command line it's executing fine. But when executing as part of a unix script it's throwing above error.

Comment: Maybe `@PACK_NAME` is undefined?

Comment: yeah you are right @Darshan. I need to use single quote for ownerID environment variable like below:mysql -uuser -ppasswrod host_name SCHMA_NAME -e "set @PACK_NAME='${ownerId}';source DELTA_TRUNCATE.sql ;"

Comment: Exactly, in your `cli`, it is already defined and hence, you don't get that error. I will put this as an answer to help anyone who sees this question in future.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are getting this error is because it's unable to evaluate `@PACK_NAME` variable while executing from unix script. So, you need to either define it before `SET` call, e.g.:

```
@PACK_NAME := 'blah';
```

Or pass it as an argument (with execute command) while executing script, e.g.:

```
set @PACK_NAME='${someValue}'
```